# printf is not printing after else

Tags: c, if-statement

I have an issue with my code, in if(flag != -1) printf is not printing the error message after entering any other number except 123 and 124. If entering 123 and 124 everything works fine, but for submitting i need to display that error message.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define distRate1 0.69
#define distRate2 0.49

struct Rental{
        int id;
        double baseDay;
        double earnings;
};

int main(){
        const int noVehicles = 2;
        int option;
        int flag;
        int tempID;
        int j;
        int i = 0;
        struct Rental vRent[] = {{123, 9.95, 0},{124, 19.95, 0}};
        printf("***** Rental Vehicle Management App *****\n");
        while(1){
                printf("\n1.) Rental Status\n");
                printf("2.) Apply Charges\n");
                printf("0.) Log out\n\n");
                printf("Please enter an option to continue: ");
                scanf("%d", &option);
                if(option == 0){
                        return 0;
                }
                if(option == 1){
                        printf("-- Rental Vehicle Status --\n\n");
                        printf("ID#      Earnings\n");
                        printf("-------- ----------\n");
                        for(j = 0; j < noVehicles; j++){
                                printf("%8d%10.2lf", vRent[j].id, vRent[j].earnings);
                        }
                }
                if(option == 2){
                        flag = -1;
                        printf("\n-- Rental Charges --\n\n");
                        printf("Enter vehicle ID: ");
                        scanf("%d", &tempID);
                        for(i = 0; i < noVehicles && flag == -1; i++){
                                if(tempID == vRent[i].id){
                                        flag = i;
                                        if(flag != -1){
                                                        int days, kms;
                                                        double BaseP, kmsC, total;
                                                        printf("Enter Rental Period (in Days): ");
                                                        scanf("%d", &days);
                                                        BaseP = (vRent[i].baseDay * days);
                                                        printf("Enter kilometers driven: ");
                                                        scanf("%d", &kms);
                                                        if(kms > 100){
                                                                kmsC = (100 * distRate1)+((kms - 100) * distRate2);
                                                        }
                                                        if(kms < 100){
                                                                kmsC = (kms * distRate1);
                                                        }
                                                        total = (kmsC + BaseP);
                                                        printf("\nBase   kmCost Total\n");
                                                        printf("====== ====== ======\n");
                                                        printf("%6.2lf %6.2lf %6.2lf\n", BaseP, kmsC, total);
                                                        vRent[i].earnings = total;
                                        } else {
                                                printf("ERROR: Vehicle ID does not exist.\n");
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(flag == -1){ printf("ERROR: Vehicle ID does not exist.\n"); }` put after for-loop.

Comment: `flag = i;  if(flag != -1){...} else {...}`: Since `flag` is set to 0 or 1(`flag = i;`) in this part, So else-block is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

You've placed the:

```
if(flag != -1){...} else{ printf("ERROR: Vehicle ID does not exist.\n"); }
```

under the conditional statement:

```
if(tempID == vRent[i].id){ ...
```

which - if true - always does:

```
flag = i;
```

meaning the first check will always be true, as `flag` is always first overriden by your loop counter `i` and therefore never negative. I think your intention was to `else` condition to relate to the `if` statement checking whether `tempID` equals to `vRent[i].id`. Putting the `else` one curly bracket lower should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It worked now, but for some reason it prints the error message twice instead of doing it once. But also error message prints every time before "Enter rental period" if i enter 124 number. With 123 it works fine.